# Can't see any difference with text-justify

Tags: css

Does "text-justify" work only in IE as stated here?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

If so, is there any way to change the way the spacing/kerning between words render in most browsers?

I've been testing some paragraphs of text formatted with `"text-align: justify"` and with `"text-justify:` (inter-word, distribute, newspaper, etc.)" and none of them makes any difference to the text.

I tested it using an iMac on Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-justify` property is IE-only. Its description in Microsoft documentation is rather vague; see my [comparison](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/justify.html#qual) of their statements with observed behavior. For texts in Latin letters, the only real difference seems to be that the values `distribute` and `newspaper` causes some of the added spacing to be directed between letters of words. (On IE. On other browsers, no effect.)

The property is included in [CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-justify) (Last Call Working Draft), with just the values `auto`, `none`, `inter-word`, and `distribute`. It is marked as being “at risk”, which means that it “may be cut from the spec during its CR period if there are no (correct) implementations”. Other browser vendors seem to be reluctant to implement this property.

On the practical side, hyphenation is usually much more important than the tuning of justification methods. Hyphenation *prevents* most of the nasty problems (need for a large amount of added spacing) that the tuning tries to fix.

P.S. Justification does not involve kerning.

Comment: Thank you Jukka! So that's why I couldn't see any difference, no matter what I did. So now I have a small problem because my client doesn't want to see "larger" gaps between some words. They made the design in Photoshop and wanted the space between words to be similar, but when I translate that to html/css I can't find a way to control that to make it look the way they want, even after using hyphen.